# Updating only metadata of existing Google Drive file Using Java

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I want to only update the meta data(for example description or file name) of existing Google drive file,
There are some documention to do so using javascript [Google Drive Update Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update?apix=true) . But no Java documentation.
Also i found code to do this

```
 private static File updateFile(Drive service, String fileId, String newTitle,
      String newDescription, String newMimeType, String newFilename, boolean newRevision) {
    try {
      // First retrieve the file from the API.
      File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

      // File's new metadata.
      file.setTitle(newTitle);
      file.setDescription(newDescription);
      file.setMimeType(newMimeType);

      // File's new content.
      java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(newFilename);
      FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(newMimeType, fileContent);

      // Send the request to the API.
      File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();

      return updatedFile;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

But in this it also upadtes content(which i dont want to do).
How can i achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more research i found the solution,

```
   File file =new File();
     file.setName("new name");
     service.files().update(fileid, file).execute();
```

This code will update the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation for updating meta data , you have separate URL ,

Upload URI, for media upload requests:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/fileId
```

Metadata URI, for metadata-only requests:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId
```

More on,

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update#try-it

And it has nothing to do with java. Hit the correct URL buddy.

And they have java sample to update the meta data(only),

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch
```

code :

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.IOException;
// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Rename a file.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param fileId ID of the file to rename.
   * @param newTitle New title for the file.
   * @return Updated file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static File renameFile(Drive service, String fileId, String newTitle) {
    try {
      File file = new File();
      file.setTitle(newTitle);

      // Rename the file.
      Files.Patch patchRequest = service.files().patch(fileId, file);
      patchRequest.setFields("title");

      File updatedFile = patchRequest.execute();
      return updatedFile;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: In my java code I have done several google drive operation like Creating folder, searching for folder, Downloading folder,getting properties fof the files. for all these i used google drive api. So i think we can do it in that fashion only without using URL.

Comment: [Google Drive update docmentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update#examples) as you can see in this documentation there is code to update metadata and content together. but not only for metadata!

Comment: Edited my answer hope its solves your problem , if so up vote and accept my answer.

Comment: Are you mentioning this [Google Drive update docmentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update#examples) ? You can see there they are sending request to API `service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();` the third parameter is file content only. we cannot call this API request without third parameter.

Comment: No goto this URL https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch

Comment: Thank you , but doesnot work with my code , getting "cannot Resolve Symbol" for Patch in line `Files.Patch patchRequest = service.files().patch(fileId, file);`

Comment: In Drive API V3 Files.Patch got replcaced with Files.update. there is some progress in my problem, still could not find the solution as im having permission issue.`com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
    {
      "code": 403,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.",
          "reason": "fieldNotWritable"
        }
      ],
      "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
    }`

Comment: thank you for helping I found th solution! @Srinivasan Sekar